# Material theme not applied correctly on pre-21 devices

Tags: android, themes, material-design

I understand that to correctly use some of the Material theme design patterns for pre API-21 devices, I'll have to include two style folders.

The theme is applied correctly on my Nexus 5 (lolipop) device, but when I run my application on a pre API-21 device (I'm using my Samsung Galaxy Note, API-16), I'm getting a blank, black screen. The application works, as I can interact with the activity (press buttons, use the keyboard, etc), but I can't see anything.

Here is my res/values-v21/themes.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkgreen</item>

</style>

</resources>
```

and here is my res/values/themes.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

</style>
</resources>
```

and I've included this line inside my manifest file under `<application>`:

```
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"
```

Am I not supposed to use the AppCompat theme for pre-lolipop devices? I'm using the v7 support library.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `res/values/themes.xml` in:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkgreen</item>
</style>
```

Then remove the same theme (`name="Theme.MyTheme"`) from `res/values-v21/themes.xml`

Comment: This both screws up the v21 theme and doesn't change anything for the older APIs...

Comment: Are you overriding this style in values-v11 or v14 ?

Comment: I only have two values folders: values, and values-v21. My min supported sdk is 15, and the target sdk is 21.

Comment: Turns out something else in my code was causing the problem. Otherwise, this is the correct solution.